# Can we write a loop or algorithm for compare elements of a list which includes tuples?

Tags: python

```
list2 = [(2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 8), (2, 12), (3, 6), (3, 12), (4, 8), (4, 12), (6, 12)]
```

Well. I have a list like this. And I need to make a new list that includes the second value of tuples which is the first value of it same, for every different first value of tuples. To make it clear, I give some examples below

In list2, the first value of the first 4th tuples is 2. So I need a list includes that this tuple's second value.

Like,
a list for the tuple's that its first value is 2, [4,6,8,12]

a list for the tuple's that its first value is 3, [6, 12]

a list for the tuple's that its first value is 4, [8, 12]

a list for the tuple's that its first value is 6, [12]

The program will be about Hasse Diagram. It will check the given numbers are be able to draw a diagram or not. I tell this for if someone has an opinion about this topic and shares it with me, I would be appreciated it.

I'll be waiting for your advice. Hope you have a nice day.

Comment: My advice would be for you to show us what your attempt at solving this looks like, and exactly how it fails to give you the expected output. We'll be waiting for your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `dict.setdefault` to group by the second values, by first, will solve that easily

```
list2 = [(2, 4), (2, 6), (2, 8), (2, 12), (3, 6),
         (3, 12), (4, 8), (4, 12), (6, 12)]

result = {}
for first, second in list2:
    result.setdefault(first, []).append(second)

print(result)  # {2: [4, 6, 8, 12], 3: [6, 12], 4: [8, 12], 6: [12]}
print(result[2])  # [4, 6, 8, 12]
```